# How to write a demo that can quickly reproduce the out-of-order execution of CPU instructions?

Tags: c++, c++11, memory

In C++11 Memory order, I think the examples are very clear, then I wrote a demo to reproduce the multi-threaded read/write disorder of atmoic variables in memory_order_relaxed. I took [the code from cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order#Relaxed_ordering) and tried to get the case where r1=r2=42.

[image]

This is my code:

```cpp
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

map<pair<int, int>, int> count;

atomic_int x(0), y(0);

void ThreadWorker1(int &r1) {
    r1 = y.load(std::memory_order_relaxed); // A
    x.store(r1, std::memory_order_relaxed); // B
    return;
}

void ThreadWorker2(int &r2) {
    r2 = x.load(std::memory_order_relaxed); // C
    y.store(42, std::memory_order_relaxed); // D
    return;
}

int Run() {
    int r1 = 0;
    int r2 = 0;
    x.store(0, std::memory_order_relaxed);
    y.store(0, std::memory_order_relaxed);

    thread work1(ThreadWorker1, ref(r1));
    thread work2(ThreadWorker2, ref(r2));
    work1.join();
    work2.join();

    count[make_pair(r1, r2)] += 1;

    if (r1 == r2 && r2 == 42) {
        cout << "Hit: " << r1 << ", " << r2 << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    return -1;
}

int main() {
    int cnt = 0;
    while (Run() != 0) {
        cnt += 1;
        if (cnt % 10000 == 0) {
            cout << cnt << endl;
        }
    }

    for (auto c : count) {
        cout << c.first.first << ", " << c.first.second << "->" << c.second << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thr progress ran long enough and didn't get the r1=r2=42 scenario. (Not doubting, of course, that if you run long enough, you can theoretically get this result)

Now the question is, how to transform the demo, without affecting the "out-of-order semantics" on the basis of, to be able to increase the probability of out-of-order execution of the cpu, to be able to quickly obtain the results of r1 = r2 = 42.

Thanks~

---

update

After thinking about it for a while, the demo here should never have a case where r1=r2=42. The purpose of CPU instruction reorder is to optimize the execution speed, that is, it will be done only when the reorder (D->C) can improve the execution efficiency of the CPU instruction pipeline. The demo here, from the results, shows that the first round does not do optimization, which means that there is no reorder, then repeat the run will not reorder. So the question arises, how to "design" the thread task here, so that the cpu execution is "just right" to optimize the execution speed by reordering instructions.

Comment: How did you compile that code? With which compiler and compilation flags? On which operating system and hardware? I suggest to ensure that your `ThreadWorker1` and `ThreadWorker2` each do much more and run for at least 10 milliseconds each

Comment: There is no guarantee that you will ever get these results on your particular combination of architecture and compiler.

Comment: `memory_order_relaxed` allows the *compiler* to reorder loads and stores. Even if a failure scenario is impossible to reproduce with the simple program above, the program is still incorrect, because there is obviously a *happens-before* dependency between the loads and stores, which is not communicated to the compiler.